# Better way to code this Symfony2 URL redirect

Tags: symfony

This works, but it's messy. I've been messing around with parameter bags but nothing works as good as the code I have.

I just want to redirect to the same page and remove a query string, but to code it better than this:

```
$r = $this->request;

$url = $r->getUri();

$replace = "abc=" . $r->query->get( 'abc' );
$url = str_replace("?".$replace, "?", $url);
$url = str_replace("&".$replace, "", $url);

$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
$this->event->setResponse($response);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the whole query string:

```php
$response = new RedirectResponse($request->getPathInfo());
```

To remove just a parameter from the query string:

```php
$route  = $request->get('_route');
$params = array_merge(
    $request->get('_route_params'), 
    $request->query->all()
);

unset($params['param_to_remove']);
// or $params['param_to_remove'] = null;

$response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate($route, $params);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how to remove one of the query sting values

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work as $request->get('_route_params') doesn't get query string params, only Symfony2 route params.

Comment: My bad. Updated the answer. Again.